# SQL запрос JOIN / w3schools

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица **Customers** которая содержит столбцы:

```
| CustomerID |  CustomerName |  ContactName |   Address |   City | PostalCode | Country |
```

Для таблицы **Customers**, написать такой **JOIN** запрос, который выберет имена всех **CustomerName**, у которых совпадает **City**, в рамках данной таблицы. Записи упорядочить по **City**.

Понимаю, что тут не обойтись без алиасов, прошу помочь указать куда двигаться для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CustomerName, A.City
FROM Customers A
JOIN Customers B ON
A.CustomerID <> B.CustomerID
AND A.City = B.City
ORDER BY A.City;
```